# MySQL / SQlite With Cursor (1 Row Upload)

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

Good Day,

I have a issue with getting all captured information within my Cursor to be populated to the MySQL server.

I have done tests, within my Toast message it does show the correct amount of lines etc, but with the loop and the respond messages all looks in order, but only one line is uploaded in the MySQL, any ideas of where I am going wrong?

- Thank You -

Code:

```
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    //if there is a network
    if (activeNetwork != null) {
        //if connected to wifi or mobile data plan
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {

            //getting all the unsynced names
            final Cursor cursor = db.getUnsyncedNames();

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int rows = cursor.getCount();
                do {


                    String custtno = cursor.getString(1);
                    String custtna = cursor.getString(2);
                    String custtnad = cursor.getString(3);


                    String outletno = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("outletno"));
                    Toast.makeText(context, "GPS Plots to Sync: " + String.valueOf(rows), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Toast.makeText(context, outletno + "\n" + custtno + "\n\n" + custtna + "\n\n" + custtnad, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    saveName(
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("outletno")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lati")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("longi")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dserial")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GPS")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GPSA")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ACC")));


                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }

            }

        }
    }




private void saveName(final String outletno, final String lati, final String longi, final String dserial, final String GPS, final String GPSA, final String ACC) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MainActivity.url_create_product,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        String Response = obj.getString("success");
                        int success = obj.getInt("success");

                        if (success == 1) {

                            Toast.makeText(context, outletno + "\n"+"Uploaded!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            db.updateNameStatus(outletno, MainActivity.NAME_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("OutletNo", outletno);
            params.put("Latitude", lati);
            params.put("Longitude", longi);
            params.put("DeviceSERIAL", dserial);
            params.put("GPS", GPS);
            params.put("NEWADDR", GPSA);
            params.put("ACC", ACC);
            return params;
        }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `cursor.isAfterLast()` condition in your while loop instead of `cursor.moveToNext()` like

```
do{
   ...
  cursor.moveToNext();
}while(!cursor.isAfterLast());
```

Comment: I have tried the above, it still only upload one line to the MySQL. Any other suggestions? - Thank You

Comment: Pleace print the log on terminal using `int rows = cursor.getCount();` . and check how many row will return it.

Comment: Sagar, it returns 6 rows, just tested, but it only uploads 1 to MySQL. - Thank You

Comment: Volley runs asynchronously, meaning it will run on its own thread while the other code continues to run. So it wont wait for the Volley response it will just start the for loop again.

Comment: Sagar, you are the man! - AsyncTask did resolve my issue. I have added my code for whole else will struggle with this issue! - Once again - Thank You

Answer (score 0):

## Try this Snippet

```
final Cursor cursor = db.getUnsyncedNames();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    try {

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){

            String custtno = cursor.getString(0);
            String custtna = cursor.getString(1);
            String custtnad = cursor.getString(2);
            
              saveName(
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("outletno")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lati")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("longi")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dserial")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GPS")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GPSA")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ACC")));
          
        cursor.moveToNext();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: still only one line in SQL. - My toast is showing that it is running through all the Cursor items, but only the 1st one is uploaded to MySQL. - Thank You

Comment: Inside the save method try using cursor.getString(number) this works in my code.

Comment: Changed the save to numbers, the same result. I think I need to try with AsyncTask as suggested above. - Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You might have declared someColumn `Not Null`

while creation of table

and

somehow `cursor.getString()` is returning `null` hence the row is not getting added in database table.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int rows = cursor.getCount();
                do {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "GPS Plots to Sync: " + String.valueOf(rows), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String onumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("outletno"));
                    String olati = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lati"));
                    String olongi = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("longi"));
                    String oserial = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dserial"));
                    String ogps = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GPS"));
                    String ogpsa = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GPSA"));
                    String oacc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ACC"));

                    //   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, currentLocation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OutletNo", onumber));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Latitude", olati));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Longitude", olongi));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DeviceSERIAL", oserial));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("GPS", ogps));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NEWADDR", ogpsa));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ACC", oacc));


                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(MainActivity.url_create_product,
                            "POST", params);

                    Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                    try {
                        int success = json.getInt("success");

                        if (success == 1) {

                            Toast.makeText(context, onumber + "\n"+"Uploaded!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            db.updateNameStatus(onumber, MainActivity.NAME_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER);
                            //      If uploaded = finish();

                        } else {
                            // failed to create product
                            //   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Need To Sync", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    cursor.moveToNext();


                } while (!cursor.isAfterLast());


            }

        }

    }

            }
```

Comment: Hi, is this the answer for your question?

Comment: Correct Bummi, Thank You